# Only allow one draggable in a droppable a time, allow any on remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Here's what I've got at the minute for my draggable and droppable sections:

```
$('.planets').draggable({
    opacity: .4,
    create: function(){$(this).data('position',$(this).position())},
    cursorAt:{left:15},
    cursor:'move',
    start:function(){$(this).stop(true,true)},
    revert : 'invalid'
});

$('.targets').droppable({
    greedy: true, ///////////////
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this ).addClass( "dropped-highlight" );
    $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', ui.draggable); ////////
    $(this).append(ui.draggable); /////////
    snapToMiddle(ui.draggable,$(this)); //This function snaps the draggable to the middle of the droppable
  },
  out: function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).removeClass( "dropped-highlight" );
    $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', '.planets'); /////////
  }
});
```

At the moment, I can stack multiple draggables in a single droppable. I only want to allow ANY ONE droppable in a draggable at a time. Once a draggable has been removed, a new one can enter that area. The lines of code with /////// are the ones I most recently added in order to try and achieve this.

Edit: This works!

```
$('.planets').draggable({
    opacity: .4,
    create: function(){$(this).data('position',$(this).position())},
    cursorAt:{left:15},
    cursor:'move',
    start:function(){$(this).stop(true,true)},
    revert : 'invalid'
});

$('.targets').droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('dropped-highlight')){
        $( this ).addClass( "dropped-highlight" );
        $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', ui.draggable);
    }
  },
  out: function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', '.planets');
            $(this).removeClass( "dropped-highlight" );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the "dropped-highlight" class is present before you append the item, and remove it on the "out" part of droppable declaration.

Something like (pseudocode):

if !this.hasClass('dropped-highlight'){

(your code)

}

and in drop:
this.removeClass('dropped-highlight').

You already have the second thing in place, just add the first.

```
if !$(this).hasClass("dropped-highlight"){
  $( this ).addClass( "dropped-highlight" );
  $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', ui.draggable);
}
```

Comment: What would I put in my function to revert it if it didn't match? return 'invalid'?

Comment: it just wont' do anything.

Comment: to rephrase, you don't need to revert it , you just don't do anything if you drop it and it already has the class

Comment: I've updated my question with what I've tried, but it still lets you drop it in there.

Comment: Worked great once I managed to figure out the niggly bits of what to delete, haha. Thank you very much! For anyone else's future reference, I've updated my original answer.